# pandas regex: is there a branch reset operator like in Perl?

Tags: pandas, regex

say I am using a regex with a backreference like e.g. (d denotes a pd.DataFrame with a column named "x"):

```
d["x"].str.replace("(abc)de|(99)\d+)","[\\1,7",regex=True)
```

However, I want the backreference to refer to either the first capture "(abc)" or the second "(99)". I could add an outer-parenthesis but this would capture portions beyond the one I would be interested in.

Now, in Perl there is this "branch reset operator" with which one could tell the regex
to assign to the backreference \1 exactly the matching branch (i.e. \1 would refer to abc or to 99 - depending on the match).

My question: Is there any possibility to get the same result with pandas?

Comment: There is no need for it here, use `d["x"].str.replace("(abc)de|(99)\d+",r"[\1\2,7",regex=True)`

Comment: Ok, I agree that with this special case there is no need for it - but my question refers to the general case

Comment: Pandas regex is based on `re`, so no, it is not possible. You can use a function based on PyPi `regex` module, then you will be able to use `(?|...|...)` there.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use lookaheads:

```
df['x'].str.replace(r'(abc(?=de)|99(?=\d+))', r'[\1,7', regex=True)
```

Example:

```
       x       out
0  abcde  [abc,7de
1   9988   [99,788
```